# Immutable js Map population

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm trying to populate an Immutable JS Map.
Given an array of fields and a form, e.g.

```
{form: 'Register', fields: ['name','firstname']}
```

I'm trying to get something like:

```
{ form :
        { name: {
               value: '',
               hasFeedback: false
              },
          firstname: {
                value: '',
               hasFeedback: false
              }
        }
}
```

My current code:

```
let newState = state;   
fields.forEach((field) => {
      newState = newstate.setIn([form, field, 'value'], '');
      newState = newstate.setIn([form, field, 'hasFeedback'], false);
    });     
return newState;
```

I'm new to the whole immutable thing: is this the right way of populating the Immutable Map? I'm a breaking any conventions on immutability? Is this the most elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any conventions, but it might be better to create the desired structure first, and then convert it using `Immutable.fromJS`. Applying mutations one-by-one, like you're doing now, will have some unnecessary overhead.

Possible refactoring of your code:

```
var form = fields.reduce((acc, f) => {
        acc.form[f] = {
            value: '',
            hasFeedback: false
        };
        return acc;
    }, {form: {}});

var immutableForm = Immutable.fromJS(form);
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about the fromJS(). Maybe I'll benchmark my code!